# How to change WebService's response's tag name in .NET/ASMX?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I have the following code:

```
namespace WebService1
{
    [System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace = "mynamespace", 
                Name = "ControlModuleService")]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [System.Web.Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute(Name = "ControlModulePort"),
    SoapDocumentService(SoapBindingUse.Literal,SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]

    public class Service1 : CommandCenter
    {

        [WebMethod, SoapDocumentMethod(
        ResponseElementName = "setConfigurationResponse")]
        public setConfigurationResponse setConfiguration(setConfigurationRequest request) 
        {

            return new setConfigurationResponse();
        }
}
```

The type:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName = "setConfigurationResponse", WrapperNamespace = "mynamespace", IsWrapped = false)]
    public partial class setConfigurationResponse
    {

        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace = "mynamespace", Order = 0)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("return", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public transaction[] @return;

        public setConfigurationResponse()
        {
        }

        public setConfigurationResponse(transaction[] @return)
        {
            this.@return = @return;
        }
    }
```

It generates the following WSDL:

```
<wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="mynamespace">
      <s:element name="request" type="tns:setConfigurationRequest" />
      <s:complexType name="setConfigurationRequest">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" form="unqualified" name="transactions" type="tns:transaction" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" form="unqualified" name="turnOnMode" type="s:boolean" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" form="unqualified" name="turnOffMode" type="s:boolean" />

        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="transaction">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" form="unqualified" name="idCC" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" form="unqualified" name="idTrans" type="s:int" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" form="unqualified" name="startTime" type="s:long" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" form="unqualified" name="state" type="s:int" />
        </s:sequence>

      </s:complexType>
      <s:element name="setConfigurationResult" type="tns:setConfigurationResponse" />
      <s:complexType name="setConfigurationResponse">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" form="unqualified" name="return" type="tns:transaction" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
...
</s:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

Why is it changing the name setConfigurationResponse to setconfigurationResult?
How can I change it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was as simple as it was complex and obscure to find:

Right above the definition of the class:

```
[XmlRoot(DataType = "setConfigurationResponse", ElementName = "setConfigurationResponse")]
```

Resulting in...

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName = "setConfigurationResponse", WrapperNamespace = "mynamespace", IsWrapped = false)]
    [XmlRoot(DataType = "setConfigurationResponse", ElementName = "setConfigurationResponse")] 
    public partial class setConfigurationResponse
    {

        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace = "mynamespace", Order = 0)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("return", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public transaction[] @return;

        public setConfigurationResponse()
        {
        }

        public setConfigurationResponse(transaction[] @return)
        {
            this.@return = @return;
        }
    }
```

and finally... :)

```
<s:element name="setConfigurationResponse" nillable="true" type="tns:setConfigurationResponse"/>
−
<s:complexType name="setConfigurationResponse">
−
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" form="unqualified" name="return" type="tns:transaction"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[XmlRoot(DataType = "setConfigurationResponse", ElementName = "setConfigurationResponse")]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName = "setConfigurationResponse", WrapperNamespace = "mynamespace", IsWrapped = false)]
    [XmlRoot(DataType = "setConfigurationResponse", ElementName = "setConfigurationResponse")] 
    public partial class setConfigurationResponse
    {

        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace = "mynamespace", Order = 0)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("return", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public transaction[] @return;

        public setConfigurationResponse()
        {
        }

        public setConfigurationResponse(transaction[] @return)
        {
            this.@return = @return;
        }
    }
```